# Does iframe loading block javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, asynchronous

Let's say you dynamically insert an iframe into the page that fetches some resources from a cross-domain. Will it block any currently executing javascript or will javascript continue to run as it loads and renders its contents?

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an extra point to duskwuff's answer: While it's true that the iframe won't block loading of content in the main page, what it will do is defer the dispatch of the main page's onload event until after its own onload event is dispatched.

This may be an issue if you have some important script that is triggered by onload, and it may give the user the impression of a slow loading experience if they notice the browser still indicates that it is loading the page.

If you want to circumvent those issues and you are able to ignore users that may have JavaScript disabled, you can write the iframe element to the DOM dynamically with JS.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't block — the contents of the frame will load asynchronously, like almost any other kind of content would.

Comment: It seems like there could/should be some synchronization between the two frames because it's possible for the javascript from one frame to call the javascript in another frame (if they are on the same domain) and I would think that would require some coordination in timing of execution.